# how to download file from sftp server using spring integration without using spring boot

Tags: java, spring-integration, spring-integration-sftp

I have a requirement where I want to use spring integration but **don't want to use spring boot** to download the file from sftp server.
I am using jcraft library here. Want to use spring-integration libraries.

```
public void downloadFileFromSftpServer () {
        String hostname = "XXX";
        String username = "XXX";
        String password = "XXX";
        String copyFrom = "XXX";
        String copyTo = "XXX";
        JSch jsch = new JSch();
        Session session;
        System.out.println("Trying to connect.....");
        try {
            session = jsch.getSession(username, hostname, 22);
            session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
            session.setPassword(password);
            session.connect();
            Channel channel = session.openChannel("sftp");
            channel.connect();
            System.out.println ("Connection successful.");
            ChannelSftp sftpChannel = (ChannelSftp) channel;
            Vector <ChannelSftp.LsEntry> vector = (Vector<ChannelSftp.LsEntry>) sftpChannel.ls(copyFrom);
            ChannelSftp.LsEntry list = vector.get(0);
            System.out.println(list.getFileName());
            String oldestFile =list.getFilename();
            sftpChannel.get(copyFrom+oldestFile, copyTo);
    }
```

Comment: This is neither a question, nor enough information... Could you please explain your problem a bit more in detail?

Comment: @deHaar was adding the information. Here it is now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the [Spring Integration Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.2.1.RELEASE/reference/html/sftp.html#sftp). It uses jsch too.

It does not need Spring Boot, it can be used in any Java/JVM application; Spring Integration has existed much longer than Spring Boot.

Comment: Thanks @Gray Russell.
It helped.